# BP sensor connected to Arduino always prints "-1" on serial.read()

Tags: arduino, sensors

I have a BP sensor connected to an Arduino, and I'm not getting serial input values. I have tried `serial.read()`: it always prints -1.

Here is [a link to the sensor](http://www.sunrom.com/p/blood-pressure-sensor-serial-output). I have tried reading from rx = 0 rx = 4 but still it gives an output as -1. You will get to know it better if open the link.

Please can you help me out? The code that I have tried:

```
char ch;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  ch=Serial.read();
  Serial.println(ch,DEC);
}
```

Comment: Wow, the code on the webpage you linked is awful.

Comment: _As far as I can see_, you're NOT calling `setup()` anywhere in your code...!?! So, if your serial is not initialized, what are you expecting to read?... Show the **complete** code please!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to `Serial.print()`to the arduino serial monitor you can't use pin D0 and D1. You'll have to use softwareSerial on e.g. pin D2 and D3.
In the top include the SoftwareSerial library

`#include <SoftwareSerial.h>`

Then instantiate it.

`SoftwareSerial blodPressure(2, 3);`  // RX, TX - can be any pins

Then in the setup begin it.

`blodPressure.begin(9600);`

Then in your loop you can use it to read from the sensor like this.

```
while(blodPressure.available()) {
  ch = blodPressure.read();
  Serial.println(ch);
}
```

Comment: No it doesnot work. It only prints 255 when setting ch as type byte